# Is there/what is a UIImagePicker allowsEditing equivalent for Windows Phone SDK?

Tags: ios, windows-phone-8, uiimagepickercontroller

At the moment, I am in the process of trying to convert my iOS app over to Windows Phone 8, however, in my iOS app, I used the UIImagePicker's allowsEditing method to get what happens in the image below.

In the image below, the user can resize the picture they have selected so they can use only the part of the picture they selected in the app, while also the picture they select gets cropped into a square for the app to easily use too.

My question is, now that I am making the app using the Windows Phone 8 SDK, is there a simple method to get this same functionality, or will I have to program this functionality in myself?

Thank you very much.

Jon.

[image: Select which part of the photo you would like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) with the `PixelHeight` and `PixelWidth` properties:

```
photoChooser.PixelHeight = 612;
photoChooser.PixelWidth = 612;
```